# Recursive Algorithm to find Kth last element in a linked list

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, wrapper

I am new to Java and I am currently looking through the book "Cracking the Coding Interview"  and their approach of finding the kth last element in a linked list by using a Wrapper Class. I have been looking at the code and I am not sure what is happening.

```
class Index{
    public int value = 0;
}

LinkedListNode kthToLast(LinkedListNode head, int k){
    Index idx = new Index();
    return kthToLast(head, k, idx);

LinkedListNode kthToLast(LinkedListNode head, int k, Index idx){
    if(head == null){
        return null;}
    LinkedListNode node = kthToLast(head.next, k, idx);
    idx.value = idx.value + 1;
    if (idx.value == k){
        return head;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Can someone explain what is happening in this code? It seems pretty confusing.
Also, why are there 2 functions kthToLast with different number of parameters passed in? (2 params initially then 3 params after that).

Also for the recursion of the kthToLast, I'm confused as how the code after the line
`LinkedListNode node = kthToLast(head.next, k, idx);`
will execute since it will recursively call itself and the subsequent code will run sometime after all the recursive calls are done.

Lastly, why are we returning head `return head`  as well as returning the node  `return node` ?

I would really appreciate if someone is able to explain the full process of what is happening in this code (and why the use of Wrapper Class as stated in the book). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A Linked List can be represented in many different ways. One of the more common approaches is as a list of nodes where each node usually has a minimum of two things: some piece of data & another node.

```
public class LinkedListNode
{
    int data;
    LinkedListNode next;
}
```

To demonstrate what's going on, lets use this example of a linked list where Node2 is your head node & we are trying to find `k=2`:

```
Node2 -> Node1 -> Node0
```

In the first method `kthToLast(LinkedListNode head, int k)`:

- A new Index is initialized with value=0
- `kthToLast(LinkedListNode head, int k, Index idx)` is called with your new Index

Starting from the head node, we recursively iterated through the entire linked list by calling the same method with `head.next` until the "base case" becomes true. Using D# to signify depth, it can be seen as:

```
D1 - Node2 (head) is NOT null so we skip the if statement

D1 - LinkedListNode node = return value of (D2) recursive call

    D2 - Node1 (head) is NOT null so we skip the if statement

    D2 - LinkedListNode node = return value of (D3) recursive call

        D3 - Node0 (head) is NOT null so we skip the if statement

        D3 - LinkedListNode node = return value of (D4) recursive call

            D4 - null (head) will return back to Depth 3
```

Now that a return statement has been called at the 4th depth, we will begin to go back up through the previous depths until we reach the kth node.

```
        D3 - LinkedListNode node = null

        D3 - idx.value = 0 + 1

        D3 - 1 != 2 therefore, return node

    D2 - LinkedListNode node = null

    D2 - idx.value = 1 + 1

    D2 - 2 == 2 therefore, return head (Node1)

D1 - LinkedListNode node = Node1

D1 - idx.value = 2 + 1

D1 - 2 != 1 therefore, return node
```

So, the 2nd Node in our LinkedList (Node1) was returned. With recursion, it helps to keep track of depth, values (& return values) at each depth, & of course your base case.